# Search query does not work as expected using multiple LIKE condition

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, search

Search query shows zero results, if using gap between words. For example:

**DB:**

```
TABLE NAME - peoples
-----------------------------------
ID   -   forename   -   surname
-----------------------------------
1        Johny          Depp
2        Kobe           Bryant
3        Random         Name
4        Mark           Zuckerberg

etc
```

**Query:**

```
$sqlnames="SELECT id, forename, surname FROM peoples WHERE forename LIKE '%$search_keyword%' OR surname LIKE '%$search_keyword%' LIMIT 20";
```

If, for example in the input i am typing: *Johny* it shows as expected: *John Depp*, or if i am typing surname: *Depp*, it also shows as expected, but if i am typing full name: *Johny Depp*, it gives zero results. How i can fix that?

Sorry for bad english, and thanks for any answers!

Comment: Maybe there is a possibility to use `AND OR`?

Comment: I am using OR in WHERE. Is this bad?

Comment: try with brackets, like `SELECT id, forename, surname FROM peoples WHERE 
(forename LIKE '%$search_keyword%' OR surname LIKE '%$search_keyword%') LIMIT 20`

Comment: @devpro same as without brackets

Comment: You need to split your search string in separate words and add an `OR` to the query for every combination of words / columns. Now you get 0 results as the text `Johny Depp` does not appear in the forename nor in the surname columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your query.

```
$sqlnames="SELECT id, forename, surname FROM peoples WHERE forename LIKE '%$search_keyword%' OR surname LIKE '%$search_keyword%' OR 
CONCAT(forename, ' ', surname ) LIKE '%$search_keyword%'
 LIMIT 20";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$sqlnames="SELECT id, forename, surname,concat(forename,' ',surname) as fullname FROM peoples WHERE fullname LIKE '%$search_keyword%' OR forename LIKE '%$search_keyword%' OR surname LIKE '%$search_keyword%' LIMIT 20";
```

Comment: @Tauras Okay fine.. :-)

Comment: @Tauras Okay no problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you are searching for full name, you are searching the "full name" inside forename or "full name" inside surname. That's why you don't get results.

Try adding another condition `OR CONCAT(forename, ' ', surname) LIKE '%$search_keyword%'`

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the words and then search:

```
$word_array = explode(" ",$search_keyword);
$sqlnames="SELECT id, forename, surname FROM peoples WHERE";
$count = 0;
foreach($word_array as $value){
    if($count == 0){
        $sqlnames .= " forname LIKE '" . $value ."'";
    }
    else{
        $sqlnames .= " OR forname LIKE '" . $value ."'";
    }
    $count = 1;
    $sqlnames .= " OR surname LIKE '" . $value ."'";    
}
$sqlnames .="LIMIT 20";
```